# Reference error By is not defined

Tags: selenium

I try to access a class using selenium and the keyword `by` , and the following error occurs :

```
ReferenceError: By is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\selenium\hello_world.js:11:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:575:3
```

The program is very simple

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var options = {
      desiredCapabilities: {
         browserName: 'chrome'
      }
     };
var client = webdriverio.remote(options);
client
    .init()
    .url('https://mail.google.com')
    .findElement(By.className("TnvOCe k6Zj8d XraQ3b")).click()
    .end();
```

Comment: This appears to be Node.js, is that right? It looks like you're mixing up functions from different languages at first glance

Comment: @mrfreester yes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using webdriverio, not Selenium. Code should be as follow.

```
client
    .init()
    .url('https://mail.google.com')
    .click('.TnvOCe.k6Zj8d.XraQ3b')
    .end();
```

You can find webdriverio API [here](http://webdriver.io/api.html).